# How can I use same instance of an angular service between components in different windows?

Tags: angular, service

I have a component `mainComponent` which calls for a service `myService` to http request some data update a BehaviorSubject `data`. Once the request is complete, a new window opens with component `otherComponent` that will display some info from `myService.data`.

However, `otherComponent` does not receive the newest value from `data` - it receives whatever `data` is initially set to.

*mainComponent.ts*

```
open() {
    this.myObs = this.myService
    .fetchObservable()
    .subscribe(() => {
        this.myService.data.subscribe(value => {
            console.log(value) //logs "new data"                
        });
        this.nativeWindow.open('workflow-editor'); //occurs after data has been updated
    })
```

*myService.ts*

```
public data: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>("old data");
    fetchObservable(){
        return this.http.get('./url')
        .pipe(
            map(res => {
                this.data.next("new data");
                console.log(this.data.value) //console.logs "new data"
                return res;
            })
        )
    }
```

*otherComponent.ts*

```
ngOnInit(){
        this.myService.data.subscribe(value => {
            console.log(value) //console.logs "old data"
        });
```

This problem only occurs when I load `otherComponent` in a new window. When I load the component in the same window, it correctly logs `"new data"`. I suspect this is because a new window loads a new version of the app, thus creating a new instance of of `myService` - one that hasn't had its `data` value updated.

Is there any way around this? Can I use the same instance of a service in two windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Write a service which can update the localstorage and also get the values. Something similar to the below snippet.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService {

  constructor() { }

  setLocalStorage(key, value) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }

  getLocalStorage(key) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  };
}
```

Using this the data will be available between windows. As you said, a new angular app instance is created when a new window is opened so the service data is reset, so you can workaround the data loss using localStorage. Below is a working example!

<kbd>**Stack Blitz Demo**</kbd>

Reference: [Storing data across windows](https://www.codediesel.com/javascript/sharing-messages-and-data-across-windows-using-localstorage/)